# How to add data from an NSTextField to a Core Data Attribute without having to press Return or Tab after editing the TextField?

Tags: cocoa, interface-builder, binding, nstextfield

I use a sheet with 3 NSTextFields and a Cancel- and OK-Button to edit the attributes of a Core Data Entity.
The text entered in the NSTextFields is only updated in the Core Data Entity if i press Tab or Return after writing in the NSTextField or if i focus another NSTextField with the mouse. If i just enter text in an NSTextField and press the OK-Button the entered text is lost.

Is there some attribute i can set in Interface Builder to change this NSTextField behaviour?

Comment: My problem would have been better described like this:
"In general, a user’s changes to a Cocoa NSTextField are saved when they finish editing (by tabbing or clicking to another field) or press return. This is fine, and it works 95% of the time. But on occasion we may find good reason to saved a user’s changes regardless of whether they’ve performed one of these completing actions.“

I found it on Red Sweater Blog: http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/229/stay-responsive

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer in my case is to check the “continuously updates value” option in the NSTextField’s value binding.
For other answers to the same problem see: Red Sweater Blog — Stay Responsive: http://www.red-sweater.com/blog/229/stay-responsive

Comment: Goes for NSTextView as well. Only wish I'd realized this morning, before I wrote the many lines I just threw away. That's what you get for not taking the time to keep it simple.