# NSTextField doesn't send values to Core Data, without user interaction

Tags: core-data, nstextfield

I have a strange problem with Core Data on Cocoa: just searched everywhere for the answer, but no luck, that's why I post this help request.

Basically, I have a serie of NSTextField which are bound to attributes of an entity. To achieve this, I simply set the value of the Bind to option to the NSArrayController, with Controller Key to selection and Model Key Path to the name of the attribute.

Everything is fine as long as I write directly in the NSTextField. When I am done, Core Data is fed automatically once I focus another NSTextField or I press Enter or Tab. 
But in case I get a value in the NSTextField indirectly (that is programmatically, without the user has to write inside it) the value of the NSTextField is not sent to Core Data.

Having checked the "continuously updates value" option in the NSTextField’s value binding did not help at all (I tried from the post [How to add data from an NSTextField to a Core Data Attribute without having to press Return or Tab after editing the TextField?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2984064/how-to-add-data-from-an-nstextfield-to-a-core-data-attribute-without-having-to-p))

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: If you're doing this from the code, do you write `willChangeValueOfKeyPath:` and `didChangeValueOfKeyPath:` around the code that changes the value for managed object's property? What's the code that changes the value of object's property?

Comment: Actually, I did not write any code. I just pass a NSString (which is created by merging two strings coming from two NSTextField's) to the stringValue of the NSTextString, which should feed core data. The problem is that unless I type something in this NSTextField Core Data doesn't receive data from it.

Answer (score 0):

Bindings are meant to keep the UI and the data behind it in sync. If you want to change the value programmatically, change the variable (or the core data object). The value in the NSTextField should be updated automatically because of the binding.

Another way to look at it is this: if setting the text programmatically triggered the binding, you would get infinite loops: NSTextField update -> data update -> NSTextfield update -> data update- > …  etc.